# How to get table row by using id in html?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get tr count  from html table  by using Id.Please check my code below

```
<table id="tableId">
<tr id="a">
    <td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr id="b">
    <td>b</td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to find rowNumber by using  row Id.for example my rowId is 'b' I want to find rowNumber for this Id.Any one help me

Comment: your intention is to use JQuery ??

Comment: And where is your actual problem, what have you tried?

Comment: I want to remove tr from table

Answer (score 9):

Here you go

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
var rowIndex = document.getElementById("b").rowIndex;
table.deleteRow(rowIndex);
```

Added the code for deletion, as requested in the comments below.

Comment: Hi it's not working for me..I want to delete this row from My table

Comment: You asked for index "user27...whatever". Use remove method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp

Answer (score 1):

It's very using with jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var rowCount = $('table#tableId tr:#b').index() + 1;
    alert(rowCount);
    $("#b").remove() // For Remove b  Row (tr) 
   });
</script>
```

Your HTML

```
<table id="tableId">
    <tr id="a">
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="b">
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the row with id b

```
$("#b").remove()
```

Comment: The question is not for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Id within any cell, then the below should work

```
document.getElementById("myID "+tempIdx).parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
```

provided table is in the below format

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p id="myID 1" />
    </td>
    <td>xxx</td>
</tr>
<td>yyy</td>
<td>
    <p id="myID 2" />
</td>
</tr>
<td>
    <p id="myID 3" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The first **.parentNode** will give the **CELL** the second will give the **ROW**, then get the ***INDEX*** from the **ROW**