# How do I update the table to show S/n in chronological order after deletion of a row in a table connected to mySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

Frontend code:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar.js";
import BarChart from "../BarChart/BarChart";
import {
  Chart,
  Tooltip,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  Title,
  LineController,
  LineElement,
  PointElement,
} from "chart.js";
import Card from "../Card/Card.js";
import CardHeader from "../Card/CardHeader.js";
import CardIcon from "../Card/CardIcon.js";
import CardBody from "../Card/CardBody";
import CardFooter from "../Card/CardFooter";
import GridItem from "../Grid/GridItem.js";
import GridContainer from "../Grid/GridContainer.js";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "../Table/Table";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import Danger from "../Typography/Danger.js";
import Warning from "@material-ui/icons/Warning";
import DateRange from "@material-ui/icons/DateRange";
import Update from "@material-ui/icons/Update";
import Store from "@material-ui/icons/Store";
import LocalOffer from "@material-ui/icons/LocalOffer";
import Accessibility from "@material-ui/icons/Accessibility";
// import { Icon, InlineIcon } from '@iconify/react';
import contentCopy from "@iconify-icons/mdi/content-copy";
import styles from "../../assets/jss/material-dashboard/views/dashboardStyle.js";

import Map from "../Map/map";

import Axios from "axios"; //axios library to make requests to api
import "./Home.css";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";
import ReactExport from "react-data-export";

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;

Chart.register(
  Tooltip,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  Title,
  LineController,
  LineElement,
  PointElement
);

function Home(props) {
  //make an axios request to get intents data from database
  const [intentsList, setintentsList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/intents").then((response) => {
      setintentsList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const updateCustomerContacted = (ID) => {
    Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {
      contacted: newContacted,
      ID: ID,
    }).then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(
        customerList.map((val) => {
          const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
            "en-CA"
          );
          const timeStr = new Date(
            val.latest_time_of_visit
          ).toLocaleTimeString();
          const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;

          return val.ID == ID
            ? {
                ID: val.ID,
                name: val.name,
                email: val.email,
                counts_of_visit: val.counts_of_visit,
                latest_time_of_visit: dateTime,
                contacted: newContacted,
              }
            : val;
        })
      );
    });
  };

  //delete function
  const deleteCustomer = (ID) => {
    Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/stats/delete/${ID}`).then(
      (response) => {
        setCustomerList(
          customerList.filter((val) => {
            return val.ID != ID;
          })
        );
      }
    );
  };

  //pagination
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
  const customersPerPage = 5; //change this number according to desired number of rows in a page
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * customersPerPage;
  const displayCustomers = customerList
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + customersPerPage)
    .map((val, key) => {
      const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
        "en-CA"
      );
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{val.name}</td>
          <td>{val.email}</td>
          <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
          <td>{dateTime}</td>
          <td>{val.contacted}</td>
          <td>
            <select
              onChange={(event) => {
                setNewContacted(event.target.value);
              }}
            >
              <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
                Select Yes/No
              </option>
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={() => {
                updateCustomerContacted(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger"
              onClick={() => {
                deleteCustomer(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  //to account for the fact that total number of customers cannot be divided equally among the pages
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(customerList.length / customersPerPage);
  //page change
  const changePage = ({ selected }) => {
    setPageNumber(selected);
  };

  //update contacted column
  const [newContacted, setNewContacted] = useState(0);

  {
    /*}
      const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(1);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/time")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setCurrentTime(data.time);
          });
      }, []);
    */
  }

  //export to csv function

  const DataSet = [
    {
      columns: [
        {
          title: "S/N",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 100 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Customer Information",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Customer Email",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Counts of Visit",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 175 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Latest Time of Visit",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Contacted?",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
      ],
      data: customerList.map((val) => [
        { value: val.ID, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.name, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.email, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.counts_of_visit, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.latest_time_of_visit, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.contacted, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
      ]),
    },
  ];

  const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);
  const classes = useStyles;

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
          {" "}
          {/*width for different screen sizes*/}
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="warning" stats icon>
              <CardIcon color="danger">
                <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Product Statistics</h4>
                {/* <Icon>content_copy</Icon> */}
              </CardIcon>
              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Used Space</p>
              <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>
                49/50 <small>GB</small>
              </h3>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <BarChart />
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter stats>
              <div className={classes.stats}>
                <Danger>
                  <Warning />
                </Danger>
                <a href="#pablo" onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}></a>
              </div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="dark" stats icon>
              <CardIcon color="dark">
                {/* <Store /> */}
                <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Locations</h4>
              </CardIcon>

              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Revenue</p>
              <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>$34,245</h3>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <Map />
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter stats>
              <div className={classes.stats}>
                <DateRange />
              </div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        {/* <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
                    <Card>
                        <CardHeader color="danger" stats icon>
                        <CardIcon color="danger">
                            <Icon>info_outline</Icon>
                        </CardIcon>
                        <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Fixed Issues</p>
                        <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>75</h3>
                        </CardHeader>
                        <CardFooter stats>
                        <div className={classes.stats}>
                            <LocalOffer />
                            
                        </div>
                        </CardFooter>
                    </Card>
                    </GridItem>
                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
                    <Card>
                        <CardHeader color="info" stats icon>
                        <CardIcon color="info">
                            <Accessibility />
                        </CardIcon>
                        <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Followers</p>
                        <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>+245</h3>
                        </CardHeader>
                        <CardFooter stats>
                        <div className={classes.stats}>
                            <Update />
                           
                        </div>
                        </CardFooter>
                    </Card>
                    </GridItem> */}
      </GridContainer>

      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="warning">
              <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Customer Information</h4>
              {/*}
              <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
                Visitors since 16th May, 2021
              </p>
                */}
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <div className="dashboardcontainer">
                <div className="container"></div>
                <table className="customertable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Customer Name</th>
                      <th>Customer Email</th>
                      <th>Counts of Visit</th>
                      <th>Latest Time of Visit</th>
                      <th>Contacted?</th>
                      <th>Edit Contacted</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{displayCustomers}</tbody>
                </table>
                <ReactPaginate
                  previousLabel={"Previous"}
                  nextLabel={"Next"}
                  pageCount={pageCount}
                  onPageChange={changePage}
                  containerClassName={"paginationBttns"}
                  pageLinkClassName={"paginationNumber"}
                  previousLinkClassName={"previousBttn"}
                  nextLinkClassName={"nextBttn"}
                  disabledClassName={"paginationDisabled"}
                  activeClassName={"paginationActive"}
                />
                <ExcelFile
                  filename="Customer Information"
                  element={
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-success float-right m-3"
                    >
                      Export to CSV
                    </button>
                  }
                >
                  <ExcelSheet
                    dataSet={DataSet}
                    name="Customer Information Report"
                  ></ExcelSheet>
                </ExcelFile>
              </div>
              {/*}
              <Table
                tableHeaderColor="warning"
                tableHead={["ID", "Name", "Salary", "Country"]}
                tableData={[
                  ["1", "Dakota Rice", "$36,738", "Niger"],
                  ["2", "Minerva Hooper", "$23,789", "Curaçao"],
                  ["3", "Sage Rodriguez", "$56,142", "Netherlands"],
                  ["4", "Philip Chaney", "$38,735", "Korea, South"],
                ]}
              />
            */}
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Backend code:

```
//set up express server
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
//set up sql server
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
//create a variable called db to make your SQL Statements
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "",
  host: "",
  password: "",
  database: "",
});

//GET REQUEST to database to retrieve customers information from database
app.get("/customers", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM customer_info", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      let row,
        res = [];
      console.log(result);
      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        row = result[i];

        let tmpd = row.latest_time_of_visit.replace("Z", "").split("T");
        let tmpt = tmpd[1].split(":");
        // check for meridian
        let meridian = "AM";
        if (+tmpt[0] > 12) {
          tmpt[0] = +tmpt[0] - 12;
          meridian = "PM";
          tmpt[0] = tmpt[0] < 10 && "0" + tmpt[0];
        }
        row.latest_time_of_visit =
          tmpd[0] + " " + tmpt.join(":") + " " + merdian;
        res.push(row);
      }

      res.send(res);
    }
  });
});

//Update customers
app.put("/update", (req, res) => {
  const ID = req.body.ID;
  const contacted = req.body.contacted;

  db.query(
    "UPDATE customer_info SET contacted = ? WHERE ID = ?",
    [contacted, ID],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});

//Delete customers
app.delete("/stats/delete/:ID", (req, res) => {
  const ID = req.params.ID;

  db.query("DELETE FROM customer_info WHERE ID = ?", ID, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//api call to pull intents data
app.get("/intents", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM data_analytics", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//check if backend server is running
app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Your server is running on port 3001");
});
```

So after I delete a row in the table, say row with ID-2, the table will show:
S/N
1
3
4
5
6

How can I make it show:
S/N
1
2
3
right after pressing the delete button which has an onClick function?

In the front end code there is a delete function commented on deleteCustomers, probably I will have to update that? Right now after deletion mySQL database updates, but it also shows S/n not in chronological order for eg.
S/N
1
3
4
5

Comment: So, basically you want the numbering to be consecutive, right?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of your actual html code, I can suggest that instead of using the actual ID in the html table column, you can use `i` iterated by 1 at each row as the display id.

Then, (for selecting the row that you want to delete) you would have to either hide your actual ID column using javascript **OR** you would have to give each row an 'id attribute' which would contain the actual ID value somewhat like this [How to get table row by using id in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224866/how-to-get-table-row-by-using-id-in-html/19224967)

In this case, you would have to re-create the html table everytime WHICH YOU MAY ALREADY BE DOING (or you may be using Ajax).

EDIT-

**(Conecpt 1 - needs recreating the table everytime)**

Create a variable `var i=0` outside your table creating code

Then instead of using `val.ID` in `<td>{val.ID}</td>`, use this `i`

And put `i++` before closing your .map tag bracket.

I guess it should work because you are not using your ID column in html table for anything except displaying, as the 'update/delete functions' are making use of the actual id's retreived directly from the table.

Hope you get an idea about what I am trying to do.

**(Concept 2)**

What you can do is create a the id column separately whose no. of rows is equal to COUNT of your result. (fill it using the conecpt of i above)

This time, you would have to remove the `<td>{val.ID}</id>` line.

So when you do DELETE, it will remove the full row exept the one cell where our i is. hence, all other column except our S/N column will move up.

Hence, at the last row there will be only 1 cell (of i) while other cells of that row have moved up. So, include code of removal of this last row/cell in the DELETE function.

Comment: hi mr.loop, my html code is actually under the comment pagination
<td>{val.ID}</td>

how can I code this to show what you stated by using ```I``` iterated by 1 ?

Comment: @max edited my answers, hope you can make use of either of the concepts

Comment: Hi mr.loop I replaced ``` <td>{val.ID}</td> ````. with ```<td>{key+1}</td>``` but every page in the table will now show 1 to 5, how can I make it such that when I go to page 2 it shows 6-10 and also now I am deleting from the sql database and the serial numbers are not in chronological order after that does it matter? So basically if I just follow your method it'll show chronological order in one page 1 to 5 for example and 1 to 5 in another page, how do I make it show 6 to 10 in another page, and ensure that mySQL database at the same time is also in chronological order?

Comment: @max 1. I think your i is getting rewrited to 0 because you defined it inside the brackets. Instead, define `var i=0` globally. Also, this would work when you recreate the table everytime after deletion otherwise no difference.

Comment: @max 2. for the matter of your database, I don't get why you'd want to do that and it also is not practical and forbidden in case of large database. If you want to try, Create a `trigger for after delete` which calls a `procedure` which contains a `loop` that `updates ID of each row that comes after the deleted row by -1`. It is possible but you got the idea how much it would be a burden.

Comment: I will need to refresh the S/n to show 1,2,3,4,5 in chronological order after deletion, because I will need to export to csv after this, regarding your point 2, what code do I insert into my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233060/discussion-between-max-and-mr-loop).